# hibernate on to many reverse query

Tags: hibernate, hql, hibernate-onetomany

I have many2one relation between 2 entities `Question` and `Answer` with many2one defined in `Answer' and no one2many defined in`Question`.

How can i query with hibernate the questions that do not have any answers without adding one2many relation in `Question` entity?

something like:

```
select distinct q from Question q
left join Answer a on a.question_id=q.id
where a.id is null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select q from Question q
where q not in (select a.question from Answer a)
```

Btw, your supplied query is "too much SQL", remember that although their syntax are similar, SQL and JPQL are conceptually different.

Comment: Thank you, that worked great. I did not know how to write the hql, so i wrote semi SQL this way for somebody like myself who usually don't read the description and skip to code :P